# PHP /Javascript validated upload form error (Coordinates)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, file-upload

I'm creating a php/JQuery avatar uploader using a live preview, which seems to be working correctly but for some reason on the /avatar.php file which the form is sending to, the information isn't being sent or processed (Values are not updating from the Javascript).  Here is my HTML / Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#previewAvatar').imgAreaSelect({ x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 210, y2: 210, aspectRatio: '1:1', maxWidth: 292, maxHeight: 292, handles: true, show : true });
});
</script>
<form id="avatarForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/avatar.php">
    <div class="formSection">
        <div class="formRight">
            <div>
                <div class="formTag">Avatar</div>
                <div class="formSubTag nameStatus errorStatus">Bigger than 300 x 300px but less than 2400k</div>
                <div id="previewOldAvatarHolder">
                    <img id="previewOldAvatar" src="uploads/avatars/<?php echo $youravatar; ?>" />
                    <img id="previewAvatar" src="#" />
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" value="" />
                <input type="file" id="avatarupload" name="avatarupload" />
            </div>
            <div class="formButtonHolder">
                <div class="formButton">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $yourid; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="avatar" name="avatar" value="<?php echo $youravatar; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" id="avatarButton" value="Click To Update &raquo;" /><div class="avatarValidation validation"></div>
                    <div class="clearLeft"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearLeft"></div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addavatar(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#previewAvatar').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#previewAvatar').imgAreaSelect({
                onSelectChange: preview,
                onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
                    $('input[name="x"]').val(selection.x1);
                    $('input[name="y"]').val(selection.y1);
                    $('input[name="w"]').val(selection.width);
                    $('input[name="h"]').val(selection.height);
                }
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#avatarupload").change(function(){
    $('#previewOldAvatar').hide();
    addavatar(this);
});
</script>
```

And here is the PHP file I'm sending it to:

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["avatarupload"]["name"]));
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["id"]);
$time = time();
$avatarid= time().'-'.mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$avatar = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["avatar"]);
$w= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["w"]);
$h= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["h"]);
$x= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["x"]);
$y= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["y"]);
$rw = 292;
$rh = 292;

$path = "../uploads/avatars/";
$unlink = "$path$avatar";

$newimage = "$path$newavatar";
$wratio = ($rw/$w); // GETTING ERROR (Warning: Division by zero in ...)
$hratio = ($rh/$h); // GETTING ERROR (Warning: Division by zero in ...)
$newW = ceil($w * $wratio);
$newH = ceil($h * $hratio);
$newimg = imagecreatetruecolor($newW,$newH);
$ext=$extension;
```

Can anyone see what the problem could be here?

Comment: Please include the output of `print_r($_POST)` in your answer.

Comment: I already did: `Warning: Division by zero in C:\AppServ\www\website.co.uk\php\avatar.php on line 35`

`Warning: Division by zero in C:\AppServ\www\website.co.uk\php\avatar.php on line 36`

Comment: No, thats not it... That's just the error message...

Comment: The values of post are not being sent to the PHP file, that's the problem, I need to know the solution fro getting the Javascript to update the Value's